# Al actualizarse la variable de vuex automaticamente se actualizen los links del navbar

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Al actualizarse la variable userId (de vuex store), necesito que automaticamente se acualizen los links del navbar, es decir, que se vuelva a realizar la condicional de mostrar distintos links. Queria saber si alguno de ustedes conoce alguna forma de escuchar un cambio en dicha variable (de vuex store) para asi poder actualizar los links del navbar.

Este es el appbar. en el cual hago las validaciones con las variables del state para mostrar los links.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app-bar
      color="deep-purple accent-4"
      dense
      dark
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon v-if='showMenu' @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

      <v-toolbar-title>Tasks App</v-toolbar-title>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <span v-if='!showMenu'>
        <v-btn
          v-for='(link, i) in links'
          :key='i'
          rounded
          color='transparent'
          elevation='0'
          :to='link.href'
          active-class='white--text text--acent-4'
        >
          <v-icon>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
          {{ link.name }}
        </v-btn>
      </span>

    </v-app-bar>

    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      absolute
      temporary
    >
      <v-list
        nav
        dense
        rounded
      >
        <v-list-item v-for='(link, i) in links' :key='i' :to="link.href">
          <v-list-item-title>
            <v-icon>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
            {{ link.name }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "AppBar",
  data() {
    return {
      showMenu: false,
      drawer: false,
      userId: this.$store.state.userId,
      links: !this.$store.state.userId ? [
        { name: "Login", icon: 'person', href: '/' },
        { name: "Signup", icon: 'person_add', href: '/signup' },
      ] : [
        { name: 'Dashboard', icon: 'dashboard', href: '/dashboard' },
        { name: "Cerrar sesion", icon: 'exit_to_app', href: '/close_session' },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    menuValidator() {
      this.showMenu = window.innerWidth <= 580
    },
    menuListeners() {
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.menuValidator)
      window.addEventListener('load', this.menuValidator);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.menuListeners();
  },
  watch: {
    userId: function() {
      // Aqui deseo que se actualize el sidebar, pero por desgracia el siguiente console.log no se ejecuta al loguearme
      console.log('ok')
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>

  *.v-btn.v-btn--router {
    color: white !important;
  }

</style>
```

Aqui el login. Que solamente llama al componente LoginForm (formulario), y LoginTitle (titulo del login).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <LoginTitle />
    <LoginForm />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import LoginTitle from '@/components/LoginTitle'
import LoginForm from '@/components/LoginForm'

export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    LoginTitle,
    LoginForm,
  }
}

</script>
```

Aqui el componente LoginForm. En el cual creo el formulario de login, y actualizo tambien las variables del store.

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col
      cols='12'
      sm='0'
      md='3'
    />
    <v-col
      cols='12'
      sm='12'
      md='6'
    >
      <v-card
        elevation='2'
        shaped
        :loading="loading"
        class='mx-auto ml-12 mr-12'
      >
        <v-card-text>
          <form>
            <v-row no-gutters>
              <v-col
                cols="12"
                sm="12"
                v-if="error !== ''"
              >
                <v-alert
                  color="red"
                  type="error"
                  elevation="5"
                  border="left"
                >
                  {{ error }}
                </v-alert>
              </v-col>
              <v-col
                cols='12'
                sm='12'
              >
                <v-text-field
                  type='text'
                  v-model='name'
                  label='Nombre'
                  color="deep-purple"
                  required
                  @keyup.enter="onSubmit"
                />
              </v-col>
              <v-col
                cols='12'
                sm='12'
              >
                <v-text-field
                  type='password'
                  v-model='password'
                  label='Contraseña'
                  color="deep-purple"
                  required
                  @keyup.enter="onSubmit"
                />
              </v-col>
              <v-col
                cols="12"
                sm="12"
              >
                <v-btn
                  block
                  @click="onSubmit"
                  color="deep-purple accent-3"
                  dark
                >
                  Empezar
                </v-btn>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </form>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
    <v-col
      cols='12'
      sm='0'
      md='3'
    />
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>

  import { sleep } from "../util";
  import { findUser } from "../requests/findUser";
  import { login } from "../requests/login";
  import { errorsValidations } from "../requests/helpers";

  export default {
    name: "LoginForm",
    methods: {
      /**
       * Show a error and delete it
       * @param msg
       * @returns {void}
       */
      async showError(msg) {
        this.loading = false;
        this.name = '';
        this.password = '';
        this.error = msg;
        await sleep({ ms: 2000 });
        this.error = '';
      },

      /**
       * Realize the login function
       * @param {any} res The user response
       * @returns {Promise<void>}
       */
      async login(res) {
        this.loading = false;
        localStorage.setItem('_', res.data.login._id);
        this.$store.commit('setUser', res.data.login);
        await this.$router.push('/dashboard');
      },

      /**
       * Execute in onSubmit event
       * @returns {Promise<void>}
       */
      async onSubmit() {
        this.loading = true;
        const res = await login({ name: this.name, password: this.password });
        await errorsValidations({ requestResponse: res, showErrorFunction: this.showError });
        await this.login(res);
      }
    },
    async mounted() {
      const { userId } = this.$store.state;

      if (userId) {
        // User is logged
        // Realizing the fetch to obtain the logged user
        // by the store saved _id
        this.loading = true;
        const user = await findUser({ _id: userId });
        await errorsValidations({ requestResponse: user, showErrorFunction: this.showError });
        await this.login({ data: { login: { ...user.data.findUser } } });
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        error: "",
        loading: false,
        name: "",
        password: "",
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Y Aqui el App.vue. En el cual defino las funciones para actualizar el usuario si esta logueado y ademas valido las consultas (si todo va bien).

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <AppBar />
    <ErrorSnackBar
      :error="error.open"
      :text="error.text"
      :timeout="error.timeout"
    />
    <v-container>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

  import AppBar from '@/components/AppBar'
  import ErrorSnackBar from "./components/ErrorSnackBar";
  import { findUser } from "./requests/findUser";
  import { errorsValidations } from "./requests/helpers";

  export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
      AppBar,
      ErrorSnackBar,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        error: {
          open: false,
          text: '',
          timeout: 2000,
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      /**
       * Show a error
       * @param {string} text Text to show
       * @returns {void}
       */
      showError(text) {
        this.error = {
          error: true,
          text: text,
          timeout: 2000, // 2 seconds...
        }
      }
    },
    async mounted() {
      const { userId } = this.$store.state;
      if (userId) {
        // Is logged saving user
        const user = await findUser({ _id: userId });
        await errorsValidations({ requestResponse: user, showErrorFunction: this.showError });
        this.$store.commit('setUser', user.data.findUser);
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Aqui el componente ErrorSnackBar. el cual simplemente muestra un snackbar en pantalla a traves de los componentes de vuetify.

```
<template>
  <v-snackbar
    v-model="error"
    :timeout="timeout"
  >
    {{ text }}

    <template v-slot:action="{ attrs }">
      <v-btn
        color="deep-purple"
        text
        v-bind="attrs"
        @click="error = false"
      >
        Cerrar
      </v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    name: "ErrorSnackBar",
    props: ['error', 'timeout', 'text']
  }

</script>
```

y aqui esta el src/store/index.js en el cual defino todas las variables de vuex store.
y ademas algunas mutaciones que me permiten alterar las variables del state.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: {},
    userId: localStorage.getItem('_') || '',
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, newUser) {
      state.user = newUser;
      state.userId = newUser._id;
    }
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

Comment: Me cuesta entender toda tu logica (hay demasiado codigo aca que sobre) y sobre todo porque hay tantos metodos async que basicamente no lo son... cuando haces el update del store, el mismo deberia reflejarse en todos los campos que corresponde.. lo unico que se me ocurre es que no estes actualizando el objeto como corresponde...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radica que estas solo accediendo a una propiedad del `store` en el objeto de data(), lo hace es solo obtener la información jamas podrás obtener los cambios del store pero como puedes "escuchar" los cambios, para eso esta `computed property`: Lo que hace es un data binding de la información del `state`.

```
computed: {
user(){
return this.$store.state.user
  }
}
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como emplearlo [Login y manejo del state](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-computed-login-2e1zn?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Gracias @Necroboy me funciono correctamente, muchisimas gracias!!